# Is there an easier way to write this method?

Tags: javascript, laravel, datetime, vue.js, datetimepicker

Hello everybody reading this.

I have a method to get todays date with current time.
If the deadline value in database is null it will get current datetime and formats it to the right format. else it will just format the deadline.

But I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this?

```
formatDateTime(deadline){
      var DateTime;

      if(deadline == null){
          var myDate = new Date();
          var month = ('0' + (myDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
          var date = ('0' + myDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
          var year = myDate.getFullYear();
          var hour = ('0' + myDate.getHours()).slice(-2);
          var minute = ('0' + myDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
          var formattedDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + date + 'T' + hour + ':' + minute;

          DateTime = moment(formattedDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');
      } else {
          DateTime = moment(deadline, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');
      };

      return DateTime;
  }
```

Comment: Just a heads up this _might_ be better placed in the Code Review Stack Exchange (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as the answer to this may be viewed as opinion based

Comment: Thanks, i will post there :)

Comment: time in javascript is made much easier when using moment.js. You can also reference the official docs to see what formatting functions already exist. https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrew said, You are already using moment

So this version will do exactly what your current function do

```
function formatDateTime(deadline){

      if(deadline == null){
          deadline = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'); 
      }

       return moment(deadline, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. This works exactly as the one i had. This looks a lot cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com), you can just pass a Date object to the `moment` function. if the function receives no arguments, it will default to the current time (same as `new Date()`).

```
formatDateTime(deadline) {
    return moment(deadline).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');
}
```